# D3 log scale displaying wrong numbers

Tags: d3.js, logarithm

I'm trying to wrap my head around the log scales provided by D3.js. It should be noted that as of yesterday, I had no idea what a logarithmic scale was.

For practice, I made a column chart displaying a dataset with four values: `[100, 200, 300, 500]`. I used a log scale to determine their height.

```
var y = d3.scale.log()
    .domain([1, 500])
    .range([height, 1]);
```

This scale doesn't work (at least not when applied to the y-axis as well). The bar representing the value 500 does not reach the top of the svg container as it should. If I change the domain to `[100, 500]` that bar does reach the top but the axis ticks does not correspond to the proper values of the bars. Because 4e+2 is 4*10^2, right?

What am I not getting here? Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VeNYj/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scale already reverses the range to account for the SVG y-coordinates starting at the top of the screen -- ie, you have `domain([min, max])` and `range([max, min])`. This means your calcs for the y position and height should be reversed because your scale already calculated y directly:

```
bars.append("rect")
    .attr("x", function (d, i) { return i * 20 + 20; })
    .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d); })
    .attr("width", 15)
    .attr("height", function (d) { return height - y(d); });
```

Here's an updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/findango/VeNYj/2/

Comment: Great! Thanks. It's still a bit confusing but I think I understand what's going on here.